# Laravel response json not working on live server, it gives connection timeout

Tags: json, ajax, laravel-5

I have deployed my project to AWS server with php7.1 mysql, and I am using laravel 5.5.
All things are working fine except ajax call response.
When I try to request through ajax call ($.post method) It show pending status for a while, but gives connection time out with status failed.
Ajax call works fine on my local setup.
Can anyone help me to short it out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: database connection not closed that's y its taking to much time ,close connections

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this guide to deploy laravel applications on EC2. This will get you a error log which can help you debug the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32948643/3429655.

If the log still doesn't come up with an error, check the access log of apache/nginx and make sure that the Ajax call does infact landup in your server and then check the error log for both apache and php. I hope you will be able to see the error in one of the logs starting from the laravel's default error log.